# Spring oracle advanced queue nullpointer on acknowledge

Tags: java, spring, oracle

Using spring to dequeue messages from a Oracle advanced queue I get the ADT message but a nullpointer on acknowledgement. Any Suggestions?

```
public class OracleAQTopicConnectionFactory {

private DataSource dataSource;

/**
 *
 * @return -
 * @throws Exception -
 */
public TopicConnectionFactory createConnectionFactory() throws Exception {
    return oracle.jms.AQjmsFactory.getTopicConnectionFactory(dataSource);
}

/**
 *
 * @param dataSource -
 */
public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
    this.dataSource = dataSource;
}
}


public class OracleAQTopicDestinationFactory implements FactoryBean {

private static final org.apache.log4j.Logger LOGGER
        = org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(OracleAQTopicDestinationFactory.class);

private TopicConnectionFactory connectionFactory;
private String queueUser;
private String queueName;

/**
 *
 * @return @throws Exception
 */
public Object getObject() throws Exception {

    TopicConnection topicConnection = connectionFactory.createTopicConnection();
    TopicSession topicSession = topicConnection.createTopicSession(true, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
    LOGGER.info("Acknowledge Mode: " + topicSession.getAcknowledgeMode());
    return ((AQjmsSession) topicSession).getTopic(queueUser, queueName);
}

/**
 *
 * @return -
 */
public Class getObjectType() {
    return javax.jms.Topic.class;
}

/**
 *
 * @return -
 */
public boolean isSingleton() {
    return false;
}

/**
 *
 * @param connectionFactory -
 */
public void setConnectionFactory(TopicConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    this.connectionFactory = connectionFactory;
}

/**
 *
 * @param queueUser -
 */
public void setQueueUser(String queueUser) {
    this.queueUser = queueUser;
}

/**
 *
 * @param queueName -
 */
public void setQueueName(String queueName) {
    this.queueName = queueName;
}
}

public class OracleObjectMessageListenerContainer extends DefaultMessageListenerContainer {

private String subscriberName;

/**
 *
 * @param subscriberName -
 */
public void setSubscriberName(String subscriberName) {
    this.subscriberName = subscriberName;
}

/**
 *
 */
public OracleObjectMessageListenerContainer() {
    super();
}

/**
 *
 * @param session -
 * @param destination -
 * @return -
 * @throws JMSException -
 */
@Override
protected MessageConsumer createConsumer(Session session, Destination destination) throws JMSException {
    return ((AQjmsSession) session).createDurableSubscriber((Topic) destination,
            subscriberName, Sync.getORADataFactory());
}

}



public class OracleNotificationListener implements MessageListener {

private static final org.apache.log4j.Logger LOGGER
        = org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(OracleNotificationListener.class);

@Override
public void onMessage(Message message) {
    try {

        AQjmsAdtMessage msg = (AQjmsAdtMessage) message;
        Sync sync = (Sync) msg.getAdtPayload();
        if (new DestinationHandler().messageHandler(sync)) {
            msg.acknowledge();
        }

    } catch (JMSException ex) {
        LOGGER.error("JMSException: " + ex.getMessage());
    }
}
}
```

On msg.acknowledge(); I get the following:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at oracle.jms.AQjmsMessage.acknowledge(AQjmsMessage.java:2036)
```

I have also tried commit(); on the session but the message is not aknowledged.

Comment: There is three kind of acknowledgements. AUTO_ACKNOWLEDG, CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE, DUPS_OK_ACKNOWLEDGE. You have set first one. In this case acknowledge is done automaticly.

Comment: AUTO_ACKNLOWLEDGE does not ack the message, neither a commit on the toppicsession or the session ack the message, it remains in the queue, using plsql to dequeue the message also remains in the queue.

Comment: What is in retention column ? 
`select name, retention from  dba_queues where name = "q_name"`.

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is to explicitly acknowledge a message then you would explicitly set the Acknowledgement mode to CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE when you create the TopicSession. However, you need to bear in mind two things:

1. You have also explicitly set the Topic Session to be transacted. In
   this case the Topic Session is going to use a local transaction and
   the acknowledgement is mostly going to be ignored. If you intend to
   manage the acknowledgement manually you may need to look at the
   transaction as well.
2. If you use CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE then you need to
   be careful in managing the acknowledgements otherwise they can begin to build up very quickly!

There's also a big caveat in that if you're using a JTA Transaction then both the `transacted` and `acknowledgeMode` parameters are ignored, as the Transaction will then be handling this aspect of the communication.

In the case where you've set AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE then the call to `acknowledge()` will try to reference the mechanism to explicitly send the acknowledgement but of course that doesn't exist, hence the `null pointer exception`